# Creating a ML Pipeline with AutoML component using Azure ML Python SDK v2

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

How would I create a machine learning pipeline with AutoML component using Azure Machine Learning Python SDK v2? I see that there is a way to pass in a custom user script as a component in this [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-python-sdk), but I want to pass in Microsoft AutoML as a component instead.

I tried doing something like below:

```
...

train_component = automl.regression(
    compute=compute_target,
    experiment_name=args.experiment_name,
    training_data=Input(type="uri_folder"),
    validation_data=Input(type="uri_folder"),
    target_column_name=args.target,
    primary_metric="accuracy",
)

...

@dsl.pipeline(
    compute=args.compute_name,
    description="AutoML pipeline",
)
def automl_pipeline(
    pipeline_job_data_input,
    pipeline_job_test_size,
):
    data_prep_job = data_prep_component(
        data=pipeline_job_data_input,
        test_size=pipeline_job_test_size,
    )
    train_job = train_component(
        training_data=data_prep_job.outputs.train_data,
        validation_data=data_prep_job.outputs.test_data,
    )
    return {
        "pipeline_job_train_data": data_prep_job.outputs.train_data,
        "pipeline_job_test_data": data_prep_job.outputs.test_data,
        "pipeline_job_model": train_job.outputs.model,
    }

pipeline = automl_pipeline(
    pipeline_job_data_input=data.name,
    pipeline_job_test_size=0.2,
)
pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    pipeline,
    experiment_name="test_pipeline",
)
```

But I am getting `TypeError: 'RegressionJob' object is not callable` error. Is this not implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to reproduce the steps and it worked for me. Follow the below steps and instructions:**

- We need to use `AutoMLStep` object when we need to use AutoML as the component for the pipeline.
- There are few steps to be followed to assign the AutoML as the component.
- `**AutoMLStep**` is having the sub class called `PipelineStep`
- There are few steps to be followed.

1. Retrieve initial dataset

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines#retrieve-initial-dataset), refers to the code block to be used for the retrieving the initial dataset. if the dataset is not created, the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-create-register-datasets) to create azure machine learning dataset.

2. Configure your storage and compute target

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines#configure-your-storage-and-compute-target), Refers to the code block to be followed for the configurations

3. Configure the training run

- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines#configure-the-training-run), refers to the code block to configure the model

4. Finally preparing the data for automated machine learning. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines#prepare-data-for-automated-machine-learning)

- To get the complete flow refer the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automlstep-in-pipelines)

**EDIT 2:**

5. For version 2 of python SDK the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-auto-train) refers the complete procedure

Document Credits: [Larry Franks](https://github.com/Blackmist) and Team

Comment: I was asking if I can do it with Python SDK azureml v2. Those guides apply to Python SDK azureml v1.

Comment: Kindly check with the EDIT 2 mentioned in the answer for Version 2 of SDK